# Understanding the syntax of numpy.r_() concatenation

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I read the following in the numpy documentation for the function [r_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

> A string integer specifies which axis to stack multiple comma
>   separated arrays along. A string of two comma-separated integers
>   allows indication of the minimum number of dimensions to force each
>   entry into as the second integer (the axis to concatenate along is
>   still the first integer).

and they give this example:

```
>>> np.r_['0,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]] # concatenate along first axis, dim>=2
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

I don't follow, what does exactly the string `'0,2'` instruct numpy to do?

Other than the link above, is there another site with more documentation about this function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`'n,m'` tells `r_` to concatenate along `axis=n`, and produce a shape with at least `m` dimensions:

```
In [28]: np.r_['0,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
Out[28]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

So we are concatenating along axis=0, and we would normally therefore expect the result to have shape `(6,)`, but since `m=2`, we are telling `r_` that the shape must be at least 2-dimensional. So instead we get shape `(2,3)`:

```
In [32]: np.r_['0,2', [1,2,3,], [4,5,6]].shape
Out[32]: (2, 3)
```

Look at what happens when we increase `m`:

```
In [36]: np.r_['0,3', [1,2,3,], [4,5,6]].shape
Out[36]: (2, 1, 3)    # <- 3 dimensions

In [37]: np.r_['0,4', [1,2,3,], [4,5,6]].shape
Out[37]: (2, 1, 1, 3) # <- 4 dimensions
```

Anything you can do with `r_` can also be done with one of the more readable array-building functions such as `np.concatenate`, `np.row_stack`, `np.column_stack`, `np.hstack`, `np.vstack` or `np.dstack`, though it may also require a call to `reshape`.

Even with the call to reshape, those other functions may even be faster:

```
In [38]: %timeit np.r_['0,4', [1,2,3,], [4,5,6]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 38 us per loop
In [43]: %timeit np.concatenate(([1,2,3,], [4,5,6])).reshape(2,1,1,3)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.2 us per loop
```

Comment: [unutbu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) wrote "I'm not a fan of this notation.", I wonder why it was introduced in numeric/numarray in the first place. Usual suspect would be matlab compatibility, but I transitioned fortran->python and I don't know enough matlab to tell for sure...

Answer (score 4):

The paragraph that you've highlighted is the two comma-separated integers syntax which is a special case of the three comma-separated syntax. Once you understand the three comma-separated syntax the two comma-separated syntax falls into place.

The equivalent three comma-separated integers syntax for your example would be:

```
np.r_['0,2,-1', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

In order to provide a better explanation I will change the above to:

```
np.r_['0,2,-1', [1,2,3], [[4,5,6]]]
```

The above has two parts:

1. A comma-separated integer string
2. Two comma-separated arrays

The comma-separated arrays have the following shapes:

```
np.array([1,2,3]).shape
(3,)

np.array([[4,5,6]]).shape
(1, 3)
```

In other words the first 'array' is '1-dimensional' while the second 'array' is '2-dimensional'.

First the `2` in `0,2,-1` means that each `array` should be upgraded so that it's forced to be at least `2-dimensional`. Since the second `array` is already `2-dimensional` it is not affected. However the first `array` is `1-dimensional` and in order to make it `2-dimensional` `np.r_` needs to add a 1 to its shape `tuple` to make it either `(1,3)` or `(3,1)`. That is where the `-1` in `0,2,-1` comes into play. It basically decides where the extra 1 needs to be placed in the shape `tuple` of the `array`. `-1` is the default and places the `1` (or `1s` if more dimensions are required) in the front of the shape `tuple` (I explain why further below). This turns the first `array's` shape `tuple` into `(1,3)` which is the same as the second `array's` shape `tuple`. The `0` in `0,2,-1` means that the resulting arrays need to be concatenated along the '0' axis.

Since both `arrays` now have a shape `tuple` of `(1,3)` concatenation is possible because if you set aside the concatenation axis (dimension 0 in the above example which has a value of 1) in both `arrays` the remaining dimensions are equal (in this case the value of the remaining dimension in both `arrays` is 3). If this was not the case then the following error would be produced:

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Now if you concatenate two `arrays` having the shape `(1,3)` the resulting `array` will have shape `(1+1,3) == (2,3)` and therefore:

```
np.r_['0,2,-1', [1,2,3], [[4,5,6]]].shape
(2, 3)
```

When a `0` or a positive integer is used for the third integer in the comma-separated string, that integer determines the start of each `array's` shape tuple in the upgraded shape `tuple` (only for those `arrays` which need to have their dimensions upgraded). For example `0,2,0` means that for `arrays` requiring a shape upgrade the `array's` original shape `tuple` should start at dimension 0 of the upgraded shape `tuple`. For `array` `[1,2,3]` which has a shape `tuple` `(3,)` the `1` would be placed after the `3`. This would result in a shape `tuple` equal to `(3,1)` and as you can see the original shape `tuple` `(3,)` starts at dimension `0` of the upgraded shape `tuple`. `0,2,1` would mean that for `[1,2,3]` the `array's` shape `tuple` `(3,)` should start at dimension 1 of the upgraded shape tuple. This means that the 1 needs to be placed at dimension 0. The resulting shape tuple would be `(1,3)`.

When a negative number is used for the third integer in the comma-separated string, the integer following the negative sign determines where original shape tuple should end. When the original shape tuple is `(3,)` `0,2,-1` means that the original shape tuple should end at the last dimension of the upgraded shape tuple and therefore the 1 would be placed at dimension 0 of the upgraded shape tuple and the upgraded shape tuple would be `(1,3)`. Now `(3,)` ends at dimension 1 of the upgraded shape tuple which is also the last dimension of the upgraded shape tuple ( original array is `[1,2,3]` and upgraded array is `[[1,2,3]]`).

```
np.r_['0,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Is the same as

```
np.r_['0,2,-1', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Finally here's an example with more dimensions:

```
np.r_['2,4,1',[[1,2],[4,5],[10,11]],[7,8,9]].shape
(1, 3, 3, 1)
```

The comma-separated arrays are:

`[[1,2],[4,5],[10,11]]` which has shape tuple `(3,2)`

`[7,8,9]` which has shape tuple `(3,)`

Both of the `arrays` need to be upgraded to `4-dimensional arrays`. The original `array's` shape tuples need to start from dimension 1.

Therefore for the first array the shape becomes `(1,3,2,1)` as `3,2` starts at dimension 1 and because two 1s need to be added to make it `4-dimensional` one 1 is placed before the original shape tuple and one 1 after.

Using the same logic the second array's shape tuple becomes `(1,3,1,1)`.

Now the two `arrays` need to be concatenated using dimension 2 as the concatenation axis. Eliminating dimension 2 from each array's upgraded shape tuple result in the tuple `(1,3,1)` for both `arrays`. As the resulting tuples are identical the arrays can be concatenated and the concatenated axis are summed up to produce `(1, 3, 2+1, 1) == (1, 3, 3, 1)`.

Comment: Thank you for the deep dive! I never understood this completely.

Answer (score 3):

The string '0,2' tells numpy to concatenate along axis 0 (the first axis) and to wrap the elements in enough brackets to ensure a two-dimensional array.  Consider the following results:

```
for axis in (0,1):
    for minDim in (1,2,3):
        print np.r_['{},{}'.format(axis, minDim), [1,2,30, 31], [4,5,6, 61], [7,8,90, 91], [10,11, 12, 13]], 'axis={}, minDim={}\n'.format(axis, minDim)

[ 1  2 30 31  4  5  6 61  7  8 90 91 10 11 12 13] axis=0, minDim=1

[[ 1  2 30 31]
 [ 4  5  6 61]
 [ 7  8 90 91]
 [10 11 12 13]] axis=0, minDim=2

[[[ 1  2 30 31]]

 [[ 4  5  6 61]]

 [[ 7  8 90 91]]

 [[10 11 12 13]]] axis=0, minDim=3

[ 1  2 30 31  4  5  6 61  7  8 90 91 10 11 12 13] axis=1, minDim=1

[[ 1  2 30 31  4  5  6 61  7  8 90 91 10 11 12 13]] axis=1, minDim=2

[[[ 1  2 30 31]
  [ 4  5  6 61]
  [ 7  8 90 91]
  [10 11 12 13]]] axis=1, minDim=3
```