# What is the value of 10j in SciPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am learning Python and SciPy. I met below two expressions:

```
a = np.concatenate(([3], [0]*5, np.arange(-1, 1.002, 2/9.0)))
```

and

```
b = np.r_[3,[0]*5,-1:1:10j]
```

The two expressions output the same array. I don't understand 10j in the 2nd expression. What is its value? Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: pls read this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468158/understanding-the-syntax-of-numpy-r-concatenation?rq=1

Comment: @anonyXmous That post doesn't seem to address the OP's question though...

Comment: googling is still our best friend :D

Comment: We were just discussing that in some detail in https://stackoverflow.com/q/48940544/901925

Answer (score 3):

It's a shorthand for creating an [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

As per the [docs for `np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

> If slice notation is used, the syntax `start:stop:step` is equivalent to `np.arange(start, stop, step)` inside of the brackets. However, if step is an imaginary number (i.e. `100j`) then its integer portion is interpreted as a number-of-points desired and the start and stop are inclusive. In other words `start:stop:stepj` is interpreted as `np.linspace(start, stop, step, endpoint=1)` inside of the brackets.

So for your specific case, `-1:1:10j` would result in a step size of (1 - (-1)) / 9 = 0.222222... which gives the following array:

```
>>> np.r_[-1:1:10j]
array([-1.        , -0.77777778, -0.55555556, -0.33333333, -0.11111111,
        0.11111111,  0.33333333,  0.55555556,  0.77777778,  1.        ])
```

While this *happens* to give you the same answer as `np.arange(-1, 1.002, 2/9.0)`, note that `arange` is *not* a good way to create such an array in general, because using non-integer step-sizes in `arange`s is a [bad idea](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.

Comment: Many thanks Praveen! I will check out the linespace method. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: Quote from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html

> However, if step is an imaginary number (i.e. 100j) then its integer portion is interpreted as a number-of-points desired and the start and stop are inclusive.

Comment: Thanks AnonyXous for the link. I did several tests using Jupityer notebook and found something which is not entirely like what the content in the link. See one example text below: np.linspace(-1, 1, 10, endpoint=True) (the same as np.r_[-1:1:10j]). The produced array has 10 elements. So 10 should the number of elements, not step in np.linspace(start, stop, step, endpoint=1). Am I right?