# numpy - explanation of the 3rd string integer of numpy.r_['string integer', array]

Tags: numpy

## Question

Please help understand in layman's words what the 3rd string integer in `numpy.r_['1,2,0', array]` is and how it works.

numpy documentation says about the 3rd integer as below, but cannot figure out what it is exactly.

> which axis should contain the start of the arrays which are less than the specified number of dimensions. In other words the third integer allows you to specify where the 1’s should be placed in the shape of the arrays that have their shapes upgraded.

[numpy.r_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html#numpy.r_)

> A string integer specifies which axis to stack multiple comma
> separated arrays along. A string of two comma-separated integers
> allows indication of the minimum number of dimensions to force each
> entry into as the second integer (the axis to concatenate along is
> still the first integer).
>
> A string with three comma-separated integers allows specification of
> the axis to concatenate along, the minimum number of dimensions to
> force the entries to, and **which axis should contain the start of the
> arrays which are less than the specified number of dimensions.** In
> other words **the third integer allows you to specify where the 1’s
> should be placed in the shape of the arrays that have their shapes
> upgraded.** By default, they are placed in the front of the shape tuple.
> **The third argument allows you to specify where the start of the array
> should be instead**. Thus, a third argument of ‘0’ would place the 1’s
> at the end of the array shape. Negative integers specify where in the
> new shape tuple the last dimension of upgraded arrays should be
> placed, so the default is ‘-1’.

Without the 3rd integer, the behavior makes sense. Frame a 2D shape and place the array elements along the 1st axis or 2nd axis.

```
print(np.r_['0,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print(np.r_['1,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
---
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]]
```

However, not sure how the 3rd integer is converting the shape. It appears `'1,2,0'` is a transpose of `'0,2,1'`, and `'1,2,1'` is that of `'0,2,0'` but no idea how this occurs.

```
print(np.r_['0,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print()
print(np.r_['0,2,0', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print(np.r_['0,2,1', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
---
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]

[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]
 [6]]
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

```
print(np.r_['1,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print()
print(np.r_['1,2,0', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print(np.r_['1,2,1', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
---
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]]

[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]]
```

The answer in [Understanding the syntax of numpy.r_() concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59568830/4281353) is touching on the part, but not sure what it is telling completely. It seems like a switch to make the shape `(1, 3)` or its transpose `(3, 1)` when doing `np.newaxis`.

> `np.r_['0,2,-1', [1,2,3], [[4,5,6]]]` has shape `(3,)` and
> shape `(1, 3)`. `np.r_` needs to add a 1 to its shape tuple to
> make it either `(1,3)` or `(3,1)`. That is where the `-1 in 0,2,-1` comes into play. It basically decides where the extra 1
> needs to be placed in the shape tuple of the array.

---

## Update

Based on the answer from hpaulj, it is much easier to think of the 3rd integer as **shift** operator.

Plus(+) is shifting the original shape from the highest dimension side to the lower in the expanded shape.

```
print(np.r_['0,5,0',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # 0 places the original shape to the highest dimension side.
print(np.r_['0,5,1',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # shift 1 to the right from highest to lower dimension.
print(np.r_['0,5,2',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # shift 2 to the right from highest to lower dimension.
print(np.r_['0,5,3',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # shift 3 to the right from highest to lower dimension.
print(np.r_['0,5,4',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # Cannot shift shape (2, 3) further than 3 in 5 dimension shape.
---
(2, 3, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 3, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Minus(-) is shifting the original shape from the lowest dimension side to the higher in the expanded shape.

```
print(np.r_['0,5,-1',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # -1 places the original shape at the lowest dimension side.
print(np.r_['0,5,-2',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # shift 1 to the left from lowest to higher dimension.
print(np.r_['0,5,-3',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # shift 2 to the left from lowest to higher dimension.
print(np.r_['0,5,-4',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # shift 3 to the left from lowest to higher dimension.
print(np.r_['0,5,-5',np.ones((2,3))].shape)  # Cannot shift shape (2, 3) further than 3 in 5 dimension shape.
---
(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
(1, 2, 3, 1, 1)
(2, 3, 1, 1, 1)
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Comment: Ultimately `r_` is just a `np.concatenate`.  That string argument lets you fine tune how it expands dimensions and which axis it concatenates on. As a default it is like `hstack`.  I recomend `np.stack` more often than `r_`.  Use `r_` but don't feel like you loose anything by not understanding it fully.

Comment: Expanding 1d (3,) arrays to 2d has 2 options, (3,1) and (1,3).  0 does one, 1 ( and -1) the other.  Experimenting with expansion to 3 or 4d might give further insights (with  (3,1,1), (1,3,1), (1,1,3) alternatives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `np.stack` I can add a new axis in 3 places relative to a 2d array.  Working with a single element tuple to highlight the new axis:

```
In [37]: np.stack((np.ones((2,3)),),0).shape     # before
Out[37]: (1, 2, 3)
In [38]: np.stack((np.ones((2,3)),),1).shape     # mid
Out[38]: (2, 1, 3)
In [39]: np.stack((np.ones((2,3)),),2).shape     # after
Out[39]: (2, 3, 1)
```

But with `r_` I can't get the (2,1,3) version:

```
In [40]: np.r_['0,3',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[40]: (1, 2, 3)
In [41]: np.r_['0,3,0',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[41]: (2, 3, 1)
In [42]: np.r_['0,3,1',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[42]: (1, 2, 3)
```

But with `r_` I can add more than one new axis:

```
In [43]: np.r_['0,4',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[43]: (1, 1, 2, 3)
In [44]: np.r_['0,4,0',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[44]: (2, 3, 1, 1)
In [45]: np.r_['0,4,1',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[45]: (1, 2, 3, 1)
In [46]: np.r_['0,4,2',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[46]: (1, 1, 2, 3)
```

With `newaxis` I can achieve all these plus:

```
In [48]: np.ones((2,3))[:,None,:,None].shape
Out[48]: (2, 1, 3, 1)
```

The latest `expand_dims` allows me to do the same:

```
In [51]: np.expand_dims(np.ones((2,3)),(1,3)).shape
Out[51]: (2, 1, 3, 1)
```

While `r_` is clever, I'm not sure it has aged well.  `stack` and `expand_dims` have been added later.  What's more valuable in `r_` is its ability to translate slice notation into `arange` or `linspace` calls.

Don't forget that you can study the code at:

```
np.lib.index_tricks.AxisConcatenator
```

Looks like the 2nd value is handled with `np.array(..., ndmin)`, and the 3rd value with a `transpose`.  The code's a bit involved.

### edit

`ndmin` adds leading dimensions as needed

```
In [82]: np.array([1,2,3], ndmin=3).shape
Out[82]: (1, 1, 3)
```

So this corresponds to the default (-1) value in `r_`.

> By default, they are placed in the front of the shape tuple

```
In [105]: np.r_['0,3',[1,2,3]].shape
Out[105]: (1, 1, 3)
In [106]: np.r_['0,3,-1',[1,2,3]].shape
Out[106]: (1, 1, 3)
```

> Thus, a third argument of ‘0’ would place the 1’s at the end of the array shape.

```
In [111]: np.r_['0,3,0',[1,2,3]].shape
Out[111]: (3, 1, 1)
In [112]: np.r_['0,3,0',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[112]: (2, 3, 1)
```

In both of these the array dimensions start at 0

> The third argument allows you to specify where the start of the array should be instead

Thus start at 1 (i.e. with one leading 1):

```
In [113]: np.r_['0,3,1',[1,2,3]].shape
Out[113]: (1, 3, 1)
In [114]: np.r_['0,3,1',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[114]: (1, 2, 3)
```

and starting at 2:

```
In [115]: np.r_['0,3,2',[1,2,3]].shape
Out[115]: (1, 1, 3)

In [116]: np.r_['0,3,2',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-116-88fa40ceb503>", line 1, in <module>
    np.r_['0,3,2',np.ones((2,3))].shape
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py", line 395, in __getitem__
    newobj = newobj.transpose(axes)
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

It can't start the (2,3) dimension at 2 in a 3d array, hence the error.  The error occurs while attempting to transpose the 3d array produced by `ndmin`.  It probably should have caught this error when constructing the `axes` argument, rather allowing `transpose` to fail.

> Negative integers specify where in the new shape tuple the last dimension of upgraded arrays should be placed

```
In [117]: np.r_['0,3,-2',[1,2,3]].shape            # 3 at -2
Out[117]: (1, 3, 1)
In [118]: np.r_['0,3,-2',np.ones((2,3))].shape     # 3 at -2
Out[118]: (2, 3, 1)
```

'-3' produces (3,1,1), over another, and error for (2,3).

Instead of focusing on where it adds the 1's, this third number makes most sense when focusing on where the original dimension(s) occur in the expanded array.  The `start of the array shape` for positives, and 'end of the array shape` for negatives'.

In other words, when an `n` ndim array is placed in a `m` ndim result, the default has leading 1's.  The `n` is at the right.  The third number shifts that `n` to the left.

Let's test that by placing a (2,) in a (5,):

```
In [121]: np.r_['0,5',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[121]: (1, 1, 1, 2, 3)                      # all the way right
In [122]: np.r_['0,5,0',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[122]: (2, 3, 1, 1, 1)                      # all the way left
In [123]: np.r_['0,5,1',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[123]: (1, 2, 3, 1, 1)
In [124]: np.r_['0,5,2',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[124]: (1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
In [125]: np.r_['0,5,-3',np.ones((2,3))].shape    
Out[125]: (1, 2, 3, 1, 1)                        # same as [123]
In [126]: np.r_['0,5,-2',np.ones((2,3))].shape
Out[126]: (1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
```

Comment: How come "with r_ I can't get the (2,1,3) version"  or "ValueError: axes don't match array" caused for ```np.r_['0,3,1',np.ones((2,3))]```? And why ```np.r_['0,4,1',np.ones((2,3))]``` adds axix on the highest and the lowest in the expanded shape as ```(1, 2, 3, 1)```? Still no clue of the behavior of the 3rd integer string.

Comment: The document says *** a third argument of ‘0’ would place the 1’s at the end of the array shape.   By default, they are placed in the front of the shape tuple***, hence I understand ```0``` is to add at the lowest and -1 at the highest in the expanded shape, but it looks the document is not cclear with other integers such as 1, 2, 3 which is less then the specified dimension as in ```which axis should contain the start of the arrays which are less than the specified number of dimensions``` in the document.

Comment: I've added some discussion.  It makes most sense when we focus on where the original `n` ndim array is placed in the new `m` ndim` array - at the right, or shifted to the left some degree or other.